# Oracle APEX: Error Message in field raises Error Message

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM apex_collections where collection_name = 'COLLECTION';

    if i = 0 then
        apex_error.add_error(
          p_message => 'Invalid Excel file!'
        , p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_with_field
        , p_page_item_name => 'P3_BROWSE_EXCEL'
        );
    end if;
END;
```

All it does is check if a collection exists. If not, it should raise an error.

I am calling this from a Process, so an Alert or something similar is no alternative.

Instead of showing the correct error message next to the `P3_BROWSE_EXCEL` - item, it shows this error on top of the page:

```
1 error has occurred

Error: Not found
```

I am 100% sure `P3_BROWSE_EXCEL` exists on that page, so why?

Comment: I've checked your code - it works. If you pass to `add_error` function wrong name of an item, APEX shows the message `Unable to find item ID for item "P3_BROWSE_EXCEL" in application "XYZ".`. So it looks like your error is in another place.

Comment: Did you try to run the page in Debug mode? It might point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple SQL validation? Validation Type - `Rows returned`, the query

```
SELECT 1 FROM apex_collections where collection_name = 'COLLECTION';
```

`Display location` - `Inline with field`, `Associated Item` - you can choose an item from a list with 100% guarantee that it exists.

Comment: Because the Excel - upload that creates the collection is a Process, which happens AFTER validations.